# Styling action bar tabs

Tags: android, tabs

I have tried many methods for styling the action bar navigation tabs and I cannot get any of them to do what I want. I just want red navigation tabs, I want to set the text color and highlight color. I can't even change the tab color. This is a very mysterious system with many intricate wizard trappings that I can't interpret or scry any meaning out of.

Manifest:

```
<application
    android:theme="@style/MyActionBarTheme"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.test.project.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/MyCustomTheme"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Styles.xml :

```
 <resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<style name="MyActionBarTheme" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light">
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBarTheme</item>
    </style>

    <style name="MyActionBarTheme" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.TabBar">
         <item name="android:background">#DC4B33</item>
    </style>

 </resources>
```

I really do not know what else I can do. I have no idea why this isn't working, I have tried many other methods but this one should work.

In MainActivity I have

```
    ab.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
```

So doing this sets my whole app to red, obviously I do not want that as that is what I explicitly specified in the style. I explicitly specified that I want the actionBar tab to be red but it makes the whole app red. Why? I just do not understand how themes work, it seems like it is just doing whatever it wants.

Can anyone explain this behavior? Why is setting the background of the ActionBar.tabbar to red making my whole app red?

Comment: this may not answer your real question, but i always use [http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-actionbarstylegenerator/](http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-actionbarstylegenerator/) , style there , download , copy and paste and last set theme in manifest. and im good to go. been using this for a long time, and it never fails me, saves you time too.

Comment: I don't want to use that because I just need to style the action bar tabs, and really I am just trying to learn how to do this not have someone do it for me.

Comment: well you can study the xml in it, and also there is also styling in action bar tabs too and yeah its your decision, as i quoted "this may not answer your real question".

Comment: Yea thanks I am looking at theirs now and I still have a red app so I think the problem is deeper than XML but who knows, android provides no documentation for this.

Answer (score 0):

I changed

```
 <style name="MyActionBarTheme" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBarTheme</item>
</style>
```

to

```
 <style name="MyActionBarTheme" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:actionBarTabBarStyle">@style/MyActionBarTheme</item>
</style>
```

making it actionBarTabBarStyle fixed it, I had no idea that was an option because there is no documentation for this from android and there are no options inside my IDE for it. I guess this is now the official documentation.